# unity-panel apps running in the background

Tags: unity, empathy, panel, vmware, jupiter

i noticed that some of my apps are in the background in unity-panel.
the apps are vmware-workstation,jupiter, empathy
this is what i mean[image]

as you can see on the left some of my apps are running but in the background 
if i didn't set my unity-panel to see-through i wouldn't have noticed it.
if i restart my laptop and start empathy it doesn't go in the background and also when 
i run `compiz --replace` the apps are back in the foreground this happens a lot when i am working my apps are suddenly in the unity-panel background?

Comment: Didnt got your question :(

Comment: how to fix that (apps in the unity-panel background i find it really annoying, i have to taskkill some apps cause when i run it again i get "another instant is already running" err box

Comment: Disable these apps from startup applications list

Comment: they are not running from startup, i start them after Ubuntu booted up

Answer (score 1):

Run this in a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I copied it from a tutorial on getting VMWare workstation to show up in the panel, but Im guessing Unity has some sort of whitelist blacklist to determine what shows up in the panel, probably to keep a consistent look and feel.  After running that command, Chrome and Google Talk showed up as well.  I seriously just copied it from another post, and remembered this post and thought it would be helpful.

http://www.gmjjavadesigns.com/content/installing-jungledisk-desktop-ubuntu-1110

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.